# dumpcap cannot save a data to a file

Tags: command-prompt, wireshark

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRz3y.png)
When I try to use "dumpcap -i num -w" to save the data to my folder, it keeps saying that the folder could not be opened: Permission denied.

I have turned off the read-only on my folder but it just doesn't work.
I want to know how to save my data in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the command prompt, it would seem that you're running on Windows, but you're incorrectly specifying a Unix-style path.

Instead of this:

```
C:\Users\bht20>dumpcap -i 4 -w /users/bht20/data/sample.pcapng
```

Try this:

```
C:\Users\bht20>dumpcap -i 4 -w C:\Users\bht20\data\sample.pcapng
```